# How to handle mergeschema option for differing datatypes in Databricks?

Tags: dataframe, scala, azure-databricks, delta-lake

```
import spark.implicits._

val data = Seq(("James","Sales",34))
val df1 = data.toDF("name","dept","age")
df1.printSchema()
df1.write.option("mergeSchema", "true").format("delta").save("/location")

val data2 = Seq(("Tiger","Sales","34") )
var df2 = data2.toDF("name","dept","age")
df2.printSchema()
df2.write.option("mergeSchema", "true").format("delta").save("/location")
df2.show(false)
```

When we write the df2 dataframe, it fails because in the delta table age is of IntergerType and the second df2 age is of StringType. How do we handle such sitaution so that the code handles this case smoothly.

Comment: You will have to provide the mode whether you need to append the data or overwrite the data. Also you need to provide the option of OverwriteSchema to True.

Comment: See this link : https://medium.com/@amany.m.abdelhalim/appending-overwriting-with-different-schema-to-delta-lake-vs-parquet-6b39c4a5d5dc

Answer (score 0):

you can just use the option of `overwriteSchema` to true and that should work.

```
val data = Seq(("James","Sales",34))
val df1 = data.toDF("name","dept","age")
df1.printSchema()
df1.write.option("mergeSchema", "true").format("delta").save("/location")

val data2 = Seq(("Tiger","Sales","34") )
var df2 = data2.toDF("name","dept","age")
df2.printSchema()
df2.write.option("overwriteSchema", "true").mode("overwrite").format("delta").save("/location")
```

Comment: if I give the mode as "overwrite" wont the existing data be overwritten? I dont want the existing data to be overwritten.

Comment: in that case you can just use the mode as append

Comment: I did try that. It gives the below
 "AnalysisException: Failed to merge fields 'age' and 'age'. Failed to merge incompatible data types IntegerType and StringType"

Comment: use standard cluster without table acl enabled to over come merge fields issue. https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/unable-to-overwrite-the-schema-of-a-delta-table/td-p/20423

Answer (score 0):

If the target schema should be unchanged, one can use `cast()`:

```
df2.withColumn("age", col("age").cast("int")).write.option("mergeSchema", "true").mode("overwrite").format("delta").save("/location")
```